# How to change tag font color?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

Why is `<%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tagquantifieds_path(t) }.join(', ') %>`'s font color staying black instead of changing like the rest of `<%= %>`?

How can we fix this? I'm sure its a simple answer I just couldn't find it on the web.

```
<div class="stats">
<ul>
<% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>

<% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
<% if result.good == true %>
<div class="green">

      <%= averaged.results.first.date_value.strftime("%b") %>:

      <%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tagquantifieds_path(t) }.join(', ') %> 

      <%= averaged.results.first.result_value %>

      <%= averaged.metric %>

</div>

<% else %>
<div class="red">

      <%= averaged.results.first.date_value.strftime("%b") %>:

      <%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tagquantifieds_path(t) }.join(', ') %> 

      <%= averaged.results.first.result_value %>

      <%= averaged.metric %>

</div>

<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you actually have .green {color:green;} in the css?

Comment: Yes @sdcr. It shows green or red for the other three attributes but not on the tag one. That remains black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because link_to is not styling, do this:

for red:

```
<%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tagquantifieds_path(t), {:style=>'color:red;'}  }.join(', ') %>
```

for green:

```
<%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tagquantifieds_path(t), {:style=>'color:green;'}  }.join(', ') %>
```

Comment: Thanks Manfergo but I get an arguments error: `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`